# Is there in Active Directory LDAP object "Everyone" with SID S-1-1-0?

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems - Here I found SID

I tried to find it in ldp.exe by CN, name, objectSid, but nothing found :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The object to which you refer is not an Active Directory Object; accordingly, an LDAP query will not return a result.

It is a universal well-known security identifier.